# How to use sended post data on server side

Tags: c#, php, post

I have a simple script to upload a file. Actually everything is working fine.

```
private void UploadCSV()
{
    Uri address = new Uri("https://www.mydomain.xy/inc.upload.php");
    string fileName = @"C:\test.csv";

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters.Add("test", "aaaa");
        client.QueryString = parameters;
        client.UploadProgressChanged += WebClientUploadProgressChanged;
        client.UploadFileCompleted += WebClientUploadCompleted;
        client.UploadFileAsync(address, "POST", fileName);

    }
}
```

Now as you can see, I try so send some data via POST `test` what contains `aaaa`. But now matter how I try to select the data serverside... there is nothing....

I tried `$_POST['test'], $_POST['data']['test']`.... but no results.

How can I access the extra Data ?

Comment: Query string contents do end up in $_GET ...

Comment: so there is no option to get a real post ?

Comment: hy Dwza,check your post data sending to the URL. you can check with URL form the browser's Inspect element Network panel in url request's header

Comment: @dinesh since i only send without response, i cant see it. But the $_GET hint solved it ^^

Comment: I'm confused there, you send fileName as POST argument but trying to get it via `$_POST['test']` ? `test` is a query parameter, how is it even related?

Comment: @CBroe post it, ill vote up and accept!

Comment: @Dwza ok you can get GET and POST value through REQUEST, any way your issue is solved right?

Comment: You should be able to get the value of file via iterating `$_POST` array in server side code.

Comment: @SelmanGenç no, i send the file but i want so send som special paramters to control the behavior in the server. e.g. select specific folder and call specific function and so on

Comment: @dinesh, im familier with php, but I never use $_REQUEST, dont ask my why... i have in mind some security issues... but im not sure :D

Comment: @Dwza so the problem is not that you can't access file but rather you can't get the value of `test` ? then the answer below should work for.

Comment: @SelmanGenç yes, and i know. This is why i told him to make a post :) but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> client.QueryString = parameters;

This will append a query string to the URL that you send the data to.

Even though the request method is POST, PHP always provides the query string parameters in `$_GET`.